# Debugging Azure deployment (unable to browse)

Tags: .net, debugging, azure, hostname

The past week or so have been very, very frustrating for me as I tried ways and means to resolve my faulty Azure deployment. For a period of time everything was fine, then one day it just refused to deploy successfully. IntelliTrace logs would speak of `TargetInvocationException` and an underlying "the connection was closed by the remote host", and I would still not know the root cause. One of the tasks during role-starting, you see, was to use a WebClient to "hit" the role once. Logs from Event Viewer didn't say much either, and I was left pretty much stranded.

Today has been a breakthrough for me as it finally started without a hitch. I am now able to use my website as per normal once I rdp into my Cloud Service. Surprisingly, however, I am not able to connect to the cloudapp hostname and I'm wondering what in the world could be causing such an issue. I have configured a port 80 http InputEndpoint, therefore to me everything should work fine.

Does anybody have any idea how I can kick this cloudapp hostname alive?

**EDIT:** If there's anything I can provide to help, I'll be sure to help. I've caught the `TargetInvocationException` in code and replaced it with a regular `System.Expression`, but it does no help as the stack trace is as follows:

```
An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check
InnerException for exception details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying
connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
remote host
```

...which leads me to believe that the "hit" is faced with a daunting 500 Internal Server Error (probably due to a missing Azure dependency or something). It would be perfect if the `Exception` could show the root cause, but it doesn't? Even when I *don't* do the "hit" nothing shows up in my Event Viewer (no "cannot find assembly..."), so right now I'm increasing the timeout in `web.config`; hopefully this will help.

But I don't think it will.

Comment: A couple of questions/suggestions:
- Does your cloudapp hostname work now? Can you reach it from your machine?
- What exactly are you using? Is it an Azure Website or a WebRole? 
- What are you trying to do? Sound like you're starting up a WebRole and trying to ping...what? The same web role? Some other website?
- A 500 server error isn't really that "dreaded". If it's happening on your website, you can just rdp into that machine and check the event log, it'll tell you what the root cause for the 500 is.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your instance?  Azure or windows NT, reboot is your first course of action.

Answer (score -2):

I would fire up something like [Telerik's Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine exactly what is going over the wire. The "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" usually means to me that I should look at the previous HTTP request-response in detail to find out what went wrong.